# Changing margins in a beamer frame

Tags: beamer, margins

I made a beamer presentation. In one of the frames I have a couple of pictures. However the left margin takes up a lot of space and the right margin is nearly zero. Having `\centering` in the figure also does not help, since the skewness of the location of the figures has to do with the margins.

How can I change margins locally? Can I use something similar to a geometry package? How do I define that within a frame?

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, table]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Frankfurt} 
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx,bm, multirow, subfig, tabularx}
\usepackage[]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows, chains,shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]{Caption 1}   
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}cXX@{}}
\begin{tabular}{cc}

\subfloat[title 1]{\includegraphics[height=5cm, width=5.5cm]{pic1.jpg}} 
   & \subfloat[title 2]{\includegraphics[height=5cm, width=5.5cm]{pic2.jpeg}}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Especially with `beamer` and its 'thousands' of templates and completely different looks it is hard to say which screw has to be turned to change the look.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I have added a pic and a MWE. Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need to change margins? Is not possible to adjust images size (`width=.5\linewidth`)? Do you know `columns` environment?

Answer (score 2):

Use for `\useoutertheme{infolines}`, this reduces the left margin, then remove the `\tabularx{}` code as indicated. Keep the inner `tabular` with `{rr}` alignment.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, table]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm, multirow, subfig,tabularx}
\usepackage[]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows, chains,shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]{Caption 1}   
\begin{figure}
\centering
%\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}rXX@{}}
\begin{tabular}{rr}
\subfloat[title1]{\includegraphics[height=5cm, width=5.5cm]{figs/dummy_fig}}
\subfloat[title2]{ \includegraphics[height=5cm, width=5.5cm]{figs/dummy_fig}} \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
%\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:  Alternate version**

If `\useoutertheme{infolines}` is no option, then a brute force method will help, depending on the size of the images, however:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, table]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm, multirow, subfig,tabularx}
\usepackage[]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows, chains,shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]{Caption 1}   
\begin{figure}
\centering
%\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}rXX@{}}
\begin{tabular}{rr}
\hspace{-0.5cm}%
\subfloat[title1]{\includegraphics[height=5cm, width=5.5cm]{figs/dummy_fig}}
\subfloat[title2]{ \includegraphics[height=5cm, width=5.5cm]{figs/dummy_fig}} \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
%\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As far as I know, the once chosen `beamer` theme in the beginning can not be changed somewhere later on, except from colour/font settings. This, however, does not effect the layout issue with outertheme `infolines` etc.

Comment: Thanks Christian. It works perfectly for this frame, but marginally affects some other slides by pushing contents to the left. Is it possible to restrict outer theme to a single frame? Or control margin in any other way?

Comment: A brute force method? Add `\hspace{-0.5cm}` just before the first `\subfloat` command ;-) I feared, that outer frames would be affected.

Answer (score 1):

No need for the table, simply place the two subfloats next to each other

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, table]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Frankfurt} 
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm, multirow, subfig, tabularx}
\usepackage[]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows, chains,shapes.multipart}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]{Caption 1}   
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[title 1]{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image.jpg}} 
\hfill
\subfloat[title 2]{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```